# Django imprime un query en HTML como lo haría en shell

Tags: python, django

Hoy es mi primer día usando Django y estoy siguiendo el tutorial de ellos. Si bien estoy modificando parámetros, básicamente es lo mismo.

Ahora, cuando quiero imprimir algo en la vista index, me imprime lo siguiente

```
<QuerySet [<*CLASE*: *RESULTADO DE MI QUERY*>]>
```

Y lo que se debería ver es solamente el resultado de query, ni el QuerySet ni la clase de la cual proviene el resultado

Mi modelo:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Usuario(models.Model):
    usuario_username = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    usuario_password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    usuario_email = models.CharField(max_length=124)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.usuario_username


class Tarea(models.Model):
    tarea_fecha_creacion = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    tarea_titulo = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    tarea_descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tarea_prioridad = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    tarea_fecha_objetivo = models.DateTimeField('Fecha objetivo',default=timezone.now)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tarea_titulo
```

El controlador:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Tarea, Usuario
# Create your views here.
from django.template import loader
def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('Todoer/index.html')
    latest_question_list = Tarea.objects.all()    
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'Todoer/index.html', context)
```

El resultado, como dije antes en mi view de html: `<QuerySet [<Tarea: Tarea prueba 1>]>`

Comment: El problema está en tu template, tienes que usar un for para imprimir ese queryset.

Comment: Muestra tu template para poder ayudarte, trata de leer bien la documentación de django, que debe ser nuestro mejor amigo en estos casos, y te daría el consejo, que `template` es una variable que no estas usando, por lo que no necesitas crearla